Density of product of random matrix with vector
Assume that we have a random matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, and we multiply it by a vector $v$ that is constant (for convenience, you can assume that it's a unit vector). Is there a general formula for determining the density function of the resulting random vector?

What do you know about the distribution of the random matrix? The components of the random vector are just linear combinations of the entries of the random matrix.

I'm looking for something similar to this https://bookdown.org/egarpor/inference/transf-rand-vecs.html. Maybe it's possible to say something by flattening the matrix and applying this result by treating it as a vector?
